# Python XML parsing missing element: 'None' vs None

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am parsing an XML file and trying to find some XML tags. I'm looking for the tag `personalDataRelated` and when running it depending on XML file, I either get one of the two values below :

```
<Element 'personalDataRelated' at 0x0000020417C86AC0>
None
```

What I do next is depending on the value I get previously my variable `data` gets  a special value attributed, but it doesn't work, and even if I get `None`, it doesn't set `data` as `Non`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

xmlfileName = 'new.xml'
xmlparse = et.parse(xmlfileName)
root = xmlparse.getroot()

print(root.find('personalDataRelated'))
if root.find('personalDataRelated') != 'None':
    data = "Oui"
else:
    data = "Non"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing against the `'None'` *string* when you should be testing against the `None` *keyword*.